# How do I automate redis flushall when it runs out of memory?

Tags: node.js, redis

My redis db runs out of memory after 2-3 day, I do flush manually. But, I want to fushall automatically in nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Read about Redis' [`maxmemory-policy`](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/6.0/redis.conf#L858) and then choose one of the `allkeys-*` policies.

Answer (score 0):

you should look why it happens at first place, maybe you could expire keys using tls [check this link](https://redis.io/commands/expire)

Other option would be just set a cronjob to flush redis once in a while(not recommended)